# confusing about (write 'a) (write #\a) (write-char #\a) (write-char 'a)

Tags: common-lisp

Using

```
(write 'a)
```

give result `A`, so I guess `'a` is the same as `#\A` (representation of character A in Lisp). But

```
(write-char 'a)
```

give error `*** - WRITE-CHAR: argument A is not a character`. So what is `'a`?

Using

```
(write #\a)
```

give result `#\a` so I guess, for `write` function, `#\a` is used as a string; but why not need put `#\a` in double quote, i.e `"#\a"`.

I already read about write, write-char function at [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm#write) and [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_cha.htm#write-char); and hard to find expected results when searching with keywords *lisp 'a*

Comment: see http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_tp_of.htm#type-of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `'a` is not a character.

Lisp has some basic datatypes:

- String, e.g. `"Hello, world!"`, the same as an array of characters
- Character, e.g. `#\A`. A lisp implementation is allowed to have multiple types of character (eg Unicode and ascii), but most do not.
- number, e.g. 1.5. These can be subdivided into fixnums, bignums, and various kinds of float, as well as subtypes like bit.
- Symbols, e.g. `'a`, sometimes written `A`. A symbol is basically a pointer to a string plus some extra information, and typically symbols are looked up (aka interned) in a hash table called a package, so that if two symbols look the same, they are equal as pointers. The lisp reader (ie parser) normally converts symbols to uppercase before interning them

Lisp code is made of lisp objects and normally a symbol is evaluated as a variable lookup, so if you try to write the symbol `A` with `(write a)` you get an error about `A` being undefined.

So how can one express the symbol `A` in lisp? Well there is a special `quote` operator:

```
CL-USER> (quote a)
A
```

The way lisp evaluates `(quote x)` is that it just returns whatever lisp object is in the source code `x`, so e.f. `(quote (a b c))` evaluates to the list of the symbols `A`, `B`, and `C`

Finally, lisp has syntactic sugar `'x` for `(quote x)`, so `'(a b c)` is exactly the same as `(quote (a b c))`

```
CL-USER> (list 'quote (list 'a 'b 'c)
'(A B C)
```

Finally, the function `write` normally tries to write objects in lisp syntax. So you get:

```
CL-USER> (write "good")
"good"
"good"
```

Note one is the string written by `write` And one is the return value printed by the REPL.

```
CL-USER> (read-from-string "A")
A
CL-USER> (read-from-string "#\\A")
#\A
```

So you see that `write` Tried to format things in a way that they can be understood by `read.`

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to put a quote in front of a symbol: `'a`. People might think that the quote is a part of the symbol.

Comment: @Dan Robertson,  when saying "the function `write` normally tries to write objects in lisp syntax", you imply that the character `a` is represented in Lisp syntax as `#\a`, so it write `#\a`, right?

Comment: @ydhhat yes, the way to write down the character `X` in lisp syntax is `#\X`, also one can write e.g. `#\Space` for the space character.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I think you’re probably right and I should be more consistent about it. I think symbols are pedagogically hard because (a) most languages don’t have them, and (b) unlike most of the fundamental objects, symbols don’t evaluate to themselves so if you want one out of the repl you need to type something slightly different into the repl. I think explaining it well as hard as you need to explain quote which requires explaining evolution which requires explaining code as made of symbols and lists which requires knowing what a symbol is.

Comment: I would first think that symbols are independent of evaluation. (a b c) is a list with three symbols. None of them are quoted. If we want to enter the list to an evaluator, then we write '(a b c). Again, none of the symbols are quoted. Explaining everything in terms of a REPL mixes execution with data representation - I think this is really confusing. People then tend to think that symbols need to be quoted everywhere... they might write ('a 'b 'c) or '('a 'b 'c).

Answer (score 2):

**Characters, Symbols, ...**

> So what is 'a

`'a` is a shorter notation for `(quote a)`. `(quote a)` evaluates to the symbol `a`.

> so I guess, for write function, #\a is used as a string; but why not need put #\a in double quote, i.e "#\a".

No, `#\a` is a character object.

**Read an intro book instead of the language reference**

You might want to read an introductory Lisp book and not the more complex language reference. I'd recommend Paul Graham's book [ANSI Common Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html) or [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) by David S. Touretzky. The latter is available for download.

Comment: I've two guesses here.First guess, `#\a` is a built-in object, and it's name is stored in symbol table of Lisp compiler and its value is character `a` (in ASCII), and `write` print the name of this object in the table, `write-char` print the value. Second guess, `#\a` is a instance of a class with a attribute that has value is character `a`; `write-char` print the value of this attribute, 'write` print value of other attribute which is the name, or print return value from a method of class (like \_\_str\_\_ in Python). It seem hard to find this kind of infomation from introductory books.

Comment: @ydhhat :  `#\a` is a character. It's not a symbol, it's not stored in a symbol table and it has no special name. It's also not an instance of a class and it has thus no attributes. You can't find information about characters in symbol tables - because it does not exist. There is nothing to guess: `#\a` is a character and just a primitive data object. Characters are a built-in data type in Common Lisp and there is a chapter devoted to them in the standard.